# Can't migrate files that contain spaces and underscore

Tags: migrations, 9

I'm migrating my D7 site to D9 and I'm getting 2K+ fail migrations for my `files` directory. It's failing because the file names contain `Spaces` and `Underscores`.

Does anyone know what I need to do to decode the `Spaces` and `Underscores`?

Here's my file.yml file:

```
uuid: 56fb6b6b-7cbe-44b6-808e-a548b8173a7b
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: upgrade_d7_file
class: Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
  - 'Drupal 7'
  - Content
migration_group: migrate_drupal_7
label: 'Public files'
source:
  plugin: d7_file
  scheme: public
  constants:
    source_base_path: 'C:wamp64/www/sseto-741'
process:
  fid:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: fid
  filename:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: filename
  source_full_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/source_base_path
        - filepath
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  uri:
    -
      plugin: file_copy
      source:
        - '@source_full_path'
        - uri
  filemime:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: filemime
  status:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: status
  created:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: timestamp
  changed:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: timestamp
  uid:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: uid
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
  source_base_path: C:wamp64/www/sseto-741/sites/default/files/
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace Space, Underscores with '**%20**' and '**%5f**'. You can use module [migrate_plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus) with process plugin [str_replace](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_plus/blob/HEAD/src/Plugin/migrate/process/StrReplace.php) like this:

```
  source_full_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/source_base_path
        - filepath
    -
      plugin: urlencode
    - 
      plugin: str_replace
      search: [" ", "_"]
      replace: ["%20", "%5f"]
```